# Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

We have a Powershell script which is using **SkypeForBusiness** module. This is being migrated to **MicrosoftTeams** and we found a problem with *Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint*:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint -TargetDomain "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"

Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

At line:1 char:1

+ Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint -TargetDomain "xxxxx.onmicrosoft. ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Teams.ConfigApi.Cmdlets.GetPowerShellEndpointCmdlet
```

The versions we are using are:

- Windows Server 2019
- PowerShell 5.1.18362.1474
- MicrosoftTeams Module: 2.3.1 (version 2.0.0 fails too)

This same command is working fine on the old installation with Windows server 2016, PS 5.1 and SkypeOnlineConnector.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this to work is to add parameter **OverrideDiscoveryUri** with $null value. Example:

```
 Get-CsOnlinePowerShellEndpoint -TargetDomain "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -OverrideDiscoveryUri $null
```

The Stacktrace for the error was pointing to an *AmbiguousParameterSet* so it seems that there is a mix of parameters, even when the unique mandatory for this cmdlet is **TargetDomain**.